# Change php info in a server

Tags: php

In my php project i have to upload  a file with 11mb. maximum uploading size is 24 mb. But sometimes i got maximum time execusion error, How i avoid this problem. Is it possible to change the max_execution_time in php configuration using any scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Note that this function has no effect when PHP is running in *safe mode*. There is no workaround other than turning off *safe mode* or changing the time limit in the php.ini.